# How to deny access to certain routes in a embedded tomcat container

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat, swagger-ui

I am using Spring-boot for java application. I am able to disable the REST API endpoints followed by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27442300/disabling-swagger-with-spring-mvc). But I want to disable swagger-ui.html for particular profiles. How to do this?

In pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can see this link : sorry for my answer a little bit short but i can't comment,it's explained here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1790230/4871427

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I want to disable swagger-ui.html only for particular profiles(example: @Profile("dev")). But I should be accessible REST API endpoints while passing parameters.

Comment: this link maybe could help you : personnaly i didn't try it but seems leg it : http://stackoverflow.com/a/6392926/4871427